# Unable to start mongodb as a service - Exception; Collection does not have UUID in KVCatalog

Tags: mongodb, linux, debian, mongodb-4.0

I have installed Mongodb 4.2

and when running

`sudo service mongod start|restart`

It does not start the server and I have the log below in mongod.log file.

`Exception in initAndListen: MustDowngrade: Collection does not have UUID in KVCatalog. Collection: local.startup_log, terminating`

Here is more detail:

```
  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7434 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=vm2851358555.bitcommand.com
  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.0
  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a4b751dcf51dd249c5865812b390cfd1c0129c30
  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0k  28 May 2019
  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian92
  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
  STORAGE  [initandlisten]
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=256M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1567525272:967263][7434:0x7fb79a56f140], txn-recover: Recovering log 16 through 17
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1567525273:183321][7434:0x7fb79a56f140], txn-recover: Recovering log 17 through 17
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1567525273:257888][7434:0x7fb79a56f140], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 16/768 to 17/256
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1567525273:401263][7434:0x7fb79a56f140], txn-recover: Recovering log 16 through 17
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1567525273:492743][7434:0x7fb79a56f140], txn-recover: Recovering log 17 through 17
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1567525273:557051][7434:0x7fb79a56f140], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (0,0)
  RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down session sweeper thread
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Finished shutting down session sweeper thread
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down journal flusher thread
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Finished shutting down journal flusher thread
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down checkpoint thread
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Finished shutting down checkpoint thread
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Downgrading WiredTiger datafiles.
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1567525275:122312][7434:0x7fb79a56f140], txn-recover: Recovering log 17 through 18
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1567525275:243324][7434:0x7fb79a56f140], txn-recover: Recovering log 18 through 18
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1567525275:351715][7434:0x7fb79a56f140], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 17/2944 to 18/256
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1567525275:482006][7434:0x7fb79a56f140], txn-recover: Recovering log 17 through 18
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1567525275:576281][7434:0x7fb79a56f140], txn-recover: Recovering log 18 through 18
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1567525275:642376][7434:0x7fb79a56f140], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (0,0)
  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: MustDowngrade: Collection does not have UUID in KVCatalog. Collection: local.startup_log, terminating
  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
  NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE!  Could you include a text-version of the output you provide in the image?  This makes it easier not only to copy/paste for people who want to dig, but also for search engines to reference in the future in the event you receive an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem can be solved by:

1. Backing-up all the databases (using `mongodump`)
2. Removing every file in `/data/db`, due to their incompatibility with
   the newer version: `rm -rf /data/db/*`
3. Restarting the MongoDB service
4. Restoring all the databases (using `mongorestore`)

Answer (score 2):

I have met similiar problem with admin db, when upgrade from old mongodb 3.4 to 4.2.

Solution is to mongodump all dbs and delete /var/lib/mongodb, then mongorestore all dbs back.

```
STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: MustDowngrade: Collection does not have UUID in KVCatalog. Collection: admin.system.users, terminating
2019-09-24T21:59:55.274+0000 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-09-24T21:59:55.274+0000 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2019-09-24T21:59:55.274+0000 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2019-09-24T21:59:55.274+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-09-24T21:59:55.274+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

The cause of problem: mongodb 4.2 will add userId with UUID value in system.user collection. Hope this will help.

When upgrading another mongo db, I met the exact same problem as yours on startup_log, it seems I did not stop the mongodb when delete the /var/lib/mongodb folder, after stop mongod and delete the /var/lib/mongodb and upgrade to 4.2, error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

A [bug report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-43132) on this issue recommended following the full upgrade path and that worked for me.  I was able to go back to my old version (3.4) when I ran into this error, and then upgrade one step at a time properly.

Specifically: upgrade just one major version at a time and check the prerequisites and upgrade steps carefully.  The most important part of this is checking your compatibility with `db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )` and make sure it matches the current version before upgrading to the next version.  Update it with `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )`

Read the full docs at pages like https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#upgrade-procedures https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0/#upgrade-procedures etc